# MySQL: Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint, unique-index

I'm executing `CreateDatabase.sql` and `SeedDatabase.sql` scripts.

In `CreateDatabase.sql`, I completely `DROP` the database and re-`CREATE` it. This works fine.

In `SeedDatabase.sql`, I `DELETE` all the data from each table and re-`INSERT` the data. This breaks on two of my `INSERT` statements.

**`Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'`**

This error doesn't make sense to me because my `UNIQUE` constraint is based on two different IDs from other tables (`UNIQUE INDEX 'PersonId_EmailId_UNIQUE' ('PersonId', 'EmailId' ASC)`). I also have other tables that are created in the same way and don't break (with valid repeating IDs).

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

**MySQL: `CreateDatabase.sql`**

```
CREATE TABLE `OLTPTEST`.`PersonEmail` (
  `PersonEmailId` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `PersonId` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `EmailId` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`PersonEmailId`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `PersonEmailId_UNIQUE` (`PersonEmailId` ASC),
  INDEX `PersonId_INDEX` (`PersonId` ASC),
  INDEX `EmailId_INDEX` (`EmailId` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `PersonId_EmailId_UNIQUE` (`PersonId`, `EmailId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `PersonEmail_PersonId_FOREIGN`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PersonId`)
    REFERENCES `OLTPTEST`.`Person` (`PersonId`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `PersonEmail_EmailId_FOREIGN`
    FOREIGN KEY (`EmailId`)
    REFERENCES `OLTPTEST`.`Email` (`EmailId`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

**MySQL: `SeedDatabase.sql`**

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
DELETE FROM `OLTPTEST`.`PersonEmail`;

ALTER TABLE `OLTPTEST`.`PersonEmail` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

INSERT INTO `OLTPTEST`.`PersonEmail` (PersonId, EmailId)
VALUES
    (1, 1)
    ,(1, 2)
    ,(2, 3)
    ,(3, 4)
    ,(4, 5)
    ;
```

This obviously isn't all the code but should be enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this ;)

You forgot to add `AUTO_INCREMENT` in table definition;

```
CREATE TABLE `OLTPTEST`.`PersonEmail` (
  `PersonEmailId` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

That's why you are getting this error;